# Weighted least squares with angular data

Tags: regression, least-squares

Suppose I have a system whose state is $\Theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_n)$, where $\theta_i\in[-\pi,\pi)$ (i.e., they are angles). I'd like to determine the most likely estimate of $\Theta$ given $m$ measurements $z_{ij}$ of the difference between two of the angles, where $z_{ij}\in[-\pi,\pi)$. In other words,

$$
z_{ij} = \begin{cases} 
(\theta_i-\theta_j)\texttt{ % }2\pi & (\theta_i-\theta_j)\texttt{ % }2\pi < \pi, \\
[(\theta_i-\theta_j)\texttt{ % }2\pi]-2\pi & (\theta_i-\theta_j)\texttt{ % }2\pi \geq \pi.
\end{cases}
$$
There are more measurements then angles in $\Theta$ (i.e., $m>n$), and each measurement has variance $\sigma^2_{ij}$.

For example, given the measurements $Z = (z_{01}, z_{12}, z_{12}, z_{13}, z_{14}, z_{23}, z_{24}, z_{34}, z_{34})$, what is the least squares estimate of $\Theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4)$?
Note that I've assumed that multiple measurements between two angles are possible, and $z_{01}$ is a direct measurement of $\theta_1$, needed to make the solution unique.

Comment: When you say these are angular data, it suggests that you might find that $\theta_1 = -3$ and $\theta_2 = 3$, and that in that case you want $z_{12} = 2\pi - 6 \in \left[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right).$ Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, that is a correct interpretation.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you should mention somewhere in the question that $z_{ij}=\theta_i-\theta_j$ is only true modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: @Rahul I've edited the question to clarify $z_{ij}$ for all cases.

Comment: A pragmatic suggestion: If $m$ isn't too large, find the least squares estimate for the equations $\theta_i-\theta_j = z_{ij} + 2 \pi d_{ij}$ for many different integer vectors $(d_{ij})$. (Letting $d_{ij}$ vary from $-n$ to $n$ should surely be enough.) Then pick the solution you like best.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED THIS IS INCORRECT
Tecnically this is straightforward. You specify the equations
$$
z_{ij}=\theta_i-\theta_j + \sigma_{ij} \epsilon_{ij}
$$
and try to minimize the error with respect to $\theta$s
$$
\sum_{ij}\epsilon_{ij}^2=\sum_{ij}\frac{1}{\sigma_{ij}^2}(z_{ij}-\theta_i+\theta_j)^2
$$
with your contsraints on $\theta$s.

EDITED
The formula above is incorrect since $z_{ij}=\theta_i-\theta_j$ by modulo $2\pi$.This is more difficult. How we can fix it? One way to avoid this to take $\sin$ from both parts and mininmize sum of squares of 
$$
\sum (\sin (z_{ij})-\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j))^2
$$
But this is awkward, nonlinear and $\sigma_{ij}$ are not properly specified here.
But  I think I see a more elegant way to solve it. I will try to give it later.

---

This problem can be converted into standard linear weighted least squares by making the variable substitution $y_{ij} = z_{ij} + y_{(i-1)i}$ for every $z_{ij}$. For the stated example, $Y=(y_{01}, y_{12}, \ldots, y_{34})$, where
$$
\begin{align}
y_{01} &= z_{01}, \\
y_{12} &= z_{12} + z_{01}, \\
y_{12} &= z_{12} + z_{01}, \\
y_{13} &= z_{13} + z_{01}, \\
y_{14} &= z_{13} + z_{01}, \\
y_{23} &= z_{23} + z_{12} + z_{01}, \\
y_{24} &= z_{24} + z_{12} + z_{01}, \\
y_{34} &= z_{34} + z_{34} + z_{12} + z_{01}, \\
y_{34} &= z_{34} + z_{34} + z_{12} + z_{01},
\end{align}
$$
and the variances of $y_{ij}$ are (for example) $\sigma^2_{y_{23}} = \sigma^2_{z_{23}} + \sigma^2_{z_{01}} + \sigma^2_{z_{01}}$, etc., assuming each $z_{ij}$ is an independent measurement. One can then adjust each $y_{ij}$ using the modulo operator (as defined in the question) to ensure $y_{ij}\in[-\pi,\pi)$.

The maximum likelihood estimate of $\Theta$ is equivalent to minimizing the negative log-likelihood of all the measurements. In other words, it is the $\Theta$ that minimizes
$$
F = (Y - H\Theta)^T\Omega(Y - H\Theta),
$$
where $\Omega=$diag$(\sigma^2_{y_{01}},\sigma^2_{y_{12}},\ldots)^{-1}$ and
$$
H = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The solution is obtained by setting $\frac{\partial F}{\partial\Theta}=0$ and solving for $\Theta$, yielding
$$
\Theta = (H^T\Omega H)^{-1}H^T\Omega Y.
$$

Comment: Copying my comment on a deleted answer: This doesn't account for the angular nature of the data. For example you could have $z_{12}=2π/3$, $z_{23}=2π/3$, $z_{34}=2π/3$, $z_{41}=0$ which can be satisfied exactly but not with your method.

Comment: @Rahul I don't get you comment and btw $z_{ij}\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So please give a contrexample that can not be solved by the LS above. There are constraints on the $\theta$ which eliminate any periodicity.

Comment: @kamek, please clarify $z_{ij}$ are exactly $\theta_i-\theta_j$ or they are defined up to $2\pi$ to fit into $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$? If $\theta_i=-\theta_j=\pi$, what is $z_{ij}$?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I apologize, that was a mistake on my part. The correct bounds are now stated. I also added another measurement (a direct measurement of one of the unknown free variables) to make the problem observable.

Comment: I still did not understand. If $θ_i=π$ and $\theta_j=-\pi/2$, what is $z_{ij}$? $-\pi/2$?

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner Sorry about the confusion. I've edited the question to clarify $z_{ij}$ for all cases.

Comment: I'm not sure your equations get one $\theta$ on the right side. For example, $\tilde z_{23}^k = z_{23}^k-\tilde z_{12}^k$ is equal to $(\theta_2 - \theta_3) - [(\theta_1 - \theta_2) - \theta_1]$, which is equal to $2\theta_2 - \theta_3$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\tilde z_{1i}^k = z_{1i}^k+\tilde z_{01}^k$? (Also noting that $\tilde z_{01}^k = z_{01}^k = -\theta_1$.).

Comment: Yes, of course "+", not "-". Whatever, you can easily rearrange $z$. First you have equation for $\theta_1$ and derive equations for $\theta_2,.4$. Using them you can eliminate one of the $\theta$ in the rest of equations.

Comment: Since you finally have only 1 variable into each equation your editing of my answer generally is correct but IMHO too complicating. You just solve equations for each $\theta$ separately.

Comment: Well solving for each $\theta$ separately isn't really that much more straightforward. In the example, there are four equations for $\theta_4$. That would mean you still need to take the weighted average of those four measurements. I've edited the answer again to reflect this.

Comment: Well, the weighted average is quite straightforward for me :). The main problem was modulo $2\pi$. Once we recalculate $y$s having only 1 $\theta$ - this problem is resolved. There is only one thing that bothers me. What is if $\sigma$ is too high, comparable to $\pi$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16646/discussion-between-kamek-and-alexander-vigodner).

Comment: kamek, I added some comment to this chat.